# Defining a class within another class and calling a parent method

Tags: python, class, inner-classes

I have c class definition and some inner class definitions for that class:

```
class DoXJob():
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        <choose an inner class to use> 

    def DoIt(self):
        pass

    def Finalize(self):
        <do finalization>

    class DoXInSomeWay():
        def __init__(self):
            ....
            ....
        def DoIt(self):
            ...

    class DoXInSomeOtherWay():
        def __init__(self):
            ....
            ....
        def DoIt(self):
            ...
```

Logic is simple, i have some inner class definitions to handle a job, and i call `DoXJob` with some parameters, it then decides which inner class will be used, and override `DoXJob.DoIt` method with the method of selected inner class method (`DoXInSomeOtherWay.DoIt` or `DoXInWay.DoIt`)

```
obj = DoXJob(param1, param2)
obj.DoIt()
```

All is fine, what i want is to trigger `DoXJob.Finalize` from the ineer classes, like calling it from the `DoXInSomeOtherWay.DoIt` or `DoXInWay.DoIt`. But i do not know how to handle this, and whether is it the right way. Or is it better to make as a `DoXJob` method call like:

```
obj = DoXJob(param1, param2)
obj.DoIt()
obj.Finalize()
```

Comment: Why don't you remove inners, make subclasses and over-write the method(s) you would to make different?

Comment: Alternately, you could take a more conventional approach to what you appear to be trying to do, i.e. the Strategy pattern.

Comment: @DonCallisto there is not much thing that will require the usage of subclassing and inheritance. Besides, inner classes will only be used within base class, so following this pattern instead of subclassing  seemed more logical to me.

Comment: Just call `DoXJob.Finalize()` directly from the inner classes.

Comment: @martineau: With what instance?

Comment: @Marcin: With the instance of `DoXJob` that created the instance of the inner class. Since inner classes will probably be created and used only by outer class instances, this could be done either by passing the outer class instance -- typically named `self` -- to the inner class's `__init__()` where it is stored for later use, or to the inner class methods each time one is called from an outer class method -- whichever is more convenient.

Comment: @martineau: right, so what you're suggesting with your "just" is one of the options in my answer. That's not a "just" - the expression you posted (`DoXJob.Finalize()`) is not the one that you would use.

Comment: @Marcin: Yes, I suppose you're right. I said "just" meaning that there's really nothing special in Python about a class being inside another -- so you'd have to write code almost no different from the way it would need to be if they hadn't been declared there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, python doesn't seem to have a way to refer to the enclosing instance.

Instead, in your outer `__init__` where you choose which inner class to use, and presumably instantiate it, you will need to pass the outer object's `self` as a parameter to the inner class instance.

Edit: Picking up the theme of a redesign - if you can simply call the `DoIt` method, then wait for its return, then you can call `Finalize` in the same place (the caller, that is), thus avoiding the need for the inner to call the outer.

Comment: Unable to Call an upper-level instance is a handycap for such a useful language.
My approach would be something like you offer in your edit, i guess... i will discard method overriding and set inner class instance to an upper class variable and make `DoIt` call from upper-level `DoIt` method. That would be a cleaner solution...

Comment: @FallenAngel: I actually think it's a good thing in some ways. What's more annoying is that names defined in the scope of an enclosing class are not in the scope of inner classes (and refer to those names on the outer class object, rather than any given instance).

Comment: thats what i mean... I just wish to access some enclosing class variables... But since that is not possible, i either have to pass the variables to inner class ìnit`as parameters or by setting inner class instance to some encolsing class variable and then define inner class variables before calling any inner class function...